# SQL WHERE with multiply JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

I'm trying to get class rooms with overlap course schedule, my tables: courses:

```
COURSE_ID    NAME
11           matematika
22           logika
```

schedule:

```
ID COURSE_ID ID_ROOM DAY HOUR
1   11  105 Mon 10am
2   11  105 Wen 10am
```

class_room:

```
ID_ROOM LOCATION CAPACITY
105 A   20
205 B   10
```

My sql is:

```
select class_room.ID_ROOM as crid, class_room.LOCATION, schedule.DAY as d, schedule.HOUR as h,  count(courses.COURSE_ID) as count 
  from schedule
  natural join class_room
  natural join courses
  group by crid, d, h
  order by count desc;
```

and I get:

```
crid LOCATION d h count
105 A   Mon 10am    3
105 A   Thu 10am    2
305 C   Mon 11am    1
105 A   Wen 10am    1
205 B   Wen 10am    1
```

But I need to show only rows where count more than 1.
I tryed

```
select class_room.ID_ROOM as crid, class_room.LOCATION, schedule.DAY as d, schedule.HOUR as h,  count(courses.COURSE_ID) as count 
  from schedule
  natural join class_room
  natural join courses
  where count>1
  group by crid, d, h
  order by count desc;
```

But I get 1054 error
How to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `where`. Use `having`

```
select class_room.ID_ROOM as crid, class_room.LOCATION, schedule.DAY as d, schedule.HOUR as h,  count(courses.COURSE_ID) as count 
  from schedule
  natural join class_room
  natural join courses
  group by crid, d, h
  having count>1
  order by count desc;
```

Comment: Great, it's working like a charm, thank you a lot, but an addition if I want to make max(count), having not working. How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `count > 1` and after the group by add `having count(courses.COURSE_ID) > 1`